# Grab the first word in a list that is found in a string. ( Python )

Tags: python, string, list, get, cpu-word

So, I have a list of words like so:

```
activationWords = ['cactus', 'cacti', 'rofl']
```

And I want to find any of those words and return the first word of any of those words appearing in a random string. I'll use this string as an example:

```
str = "Wow, rofl I found a cactus in a cacti pile."
```

As you can see with the above example string, the first instance of a word in the list is "rofl". I want to be able to detect that and return the word into a string that I can use to my discretion. How would I do this?

Keep in mind that that string is just an example. Each time I run this it will be using a different string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.find()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) here:

```
>>> activationWords = ['cactus', 'cacti', 'rofl']
>>> s = "Wow, rofl I found a cactus in a cacti pile."
>>> temp = [(s.find(i), i) for i in activationWords if i in s]
>>> print temp
[(20, 'cactus'), (32, 'cacti'), (5, 'rofl')]
>>> print min(temp)[1]
rofl
```

`str.find()` finds where the string is in the other string. It returns the index of the first letter.

`[(s.find(i), i) for i in activationWords]` is a list comprehension that returns a list of tuples, the first item being the result of `str.find()`, the second being the word.

Then we use [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) here to get the lowest number, and `[1]` to get the word.

Note that you should not name a string `str`. It overrides the built-in type.