# Python, Output all words from a list found in a string in order of apperance

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function takes a list of words that I want to return, if they appear in the string, as a string separated by " ". However, right now they will be returned in the order of apperance in my list passed to the function. How can I modify my function so they are returned in the order of apperance in the string ?

Only similar post I found was this one which return the first word and its in python 2.x :
[Grab the first word in a list that is found in a string. ( Python )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807905/grab-the-first-word-in-a-list-that-is-found-in-a-string-python)

```
def ifExiste(set):
        count_tweet_adding = 0
        tempvalue = []
        value = ""
        x=0
        old_count = count_tweet_adding
        for element in set:
            if (word_tweet.find(element) >= 0):
                tempvalue.append(element.strip())
                count_tweet_adding +=1
                value = tempvalue[0] 
        if (old_count == count_tweet_adding):
            value = "NaN"
        while x < len(tempvalue)-1:
            x += 1 
            value = value + " " + tempvalue[x]
        return value
```

EDIT :
Here is how I did it:

I added a loop to filter words that are in both the string and my list of words and then used this filtered list with the 'brute force' method to check my string letter by letter. I also added a replace lign to take the word I picked up out of the string so I can capture it twice if it appears twice in my string.

```
def ifExiste(text, input_list):
    count_tweet_adding = 0
    tempvalue = []
    value = ""
    old_count = count_tweet_adding

    filtered_input_list = []
    for word in input_list:
        if word in text:
            filtered_input_list.append(word)

    for length in range(len(text)):
        for word in filtered_input_list:
            if word in text[:length+1]:
                tempvalue.append(word)
                text = text[:length+1].replace(word,'')+text[length+2:]
                count_tweet_adding +=1
    tempvalue = map(str.strip, tempvalue)
    value = " ".join(tempvalue)

    if (old_count == count_tweet_adding):
        value = "NaN"

    return value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty (bruteforce) solution.

Assume that you have a string of the following sort to compare against, since you mentioned the separator (or delimiter) is "".

`>>> s = "herearesomewordsinastringinsomeorder"`

Now assume you have a list `l`, the words from which you want to compare against `s` and document.

`>>> l = ['string', 'the', 'in', 'appear', 'words', 'these', 'do']`

You could then initialize a new list, `newlist`, to document the words in `l` in the same order they appear in `s`.

`>>> newlist = []`

Then you could write a for-each-in loop of the sort:

```
>>> for length in range(len(s)):
...     for word in l:
...             if word in s[:length+1] and word not in newlist:
...                     newlist.append(word)
```

Which, on evaluation, would give you:

```
>>> newlist
['words', 'in', 'string']
```

in the order they appeared in `s`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. Now what if a word appears twice in the string and I want to capture it twice ? I guess i need to edit my string to remove the captured word at some point right ? Any tip on doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able do this with an expression!

```
def fn(s, input_list):
    return list(x for x in s.split() if x in input_list)
```

---

This works by first making your string `s` into a list, then iterating over it, finding all the members that are in `input_list`

```
>>> fn("one two three", ["three", "two", "missing"])
['two', 'three']
```

This should be perfectly reasonable for small strings

If you want to create a new string, you can use `" ".join()"`

```
>>> " ".join(fn("one two three", ["three", "two", "missing"]))
'two three
```

If you always want to return a new string, you can directly return the joined value instead of creating a new list.

```
def fn(s, input_list):
    return " ".join(x for x in s.split() if x in input_list)
```